Issue with python/keras implementation of Generative Adversarial Network (GAN) on MacBook
I'm very new to keras and Generative Adversarial Networks (GAN). When I attempted to run this script for a simple GAN on my MacBook, I got:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/programming/python_image_learning/./248-cifar_GAN.py", line 240, in <module>
    train(generator, discriminator, gan_model, dataset, latent_dim, n_epochs=2)
  File "~/Library/CloudStorage/Dropbox/programming/python_image_learning/./248-cifar_GAN.py", line 195, in train
    d_loss_real, _ = d_model.train_on_batch(X_real, y_real) 
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/pyimage/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 549, in train_on_batch
    logs = self.train_function(data())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/pyimage/lib/python3.12/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/pyimage/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 121, in one_step_on_iterator
    outputs = self.distribute_strategy.run(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/pyimage/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 108, in one_step_on_data
    return self.train_step(data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "~/miniconda3/envs/pyimage/lib/python3.12/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 61, in train_step
    self._loss_tracker.update_state(
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update_state'

I got the same error when I tried other scripts.
However, these scripts ran well on Google Colab, making me speculate that something is wrong with my local coding environment:
MacBook Pro 16-in, 2019
Bash shell
conda 24.9.2
Python 3.12.7
tensorflow 2.16.2
keras 3.6.0

Nonetheless, I also know that a simple CNN or Unet (e.g. this) works well on my laptop, so the problem seems to be the connection between generator and discriminator in this environment. I made a few attempts to connect generator and discriminator, but the only way I could get rid of this problem is to set the input layer of the discriminator as a clone of the generator output, like below:
generator_inputs = Input(shape = (100, ))
G1d1, G1l1, G1n1 = dense_leak_norm(parents = generator_inputs, input_shape = (100, ))
G2d1, G2l1, G2n1 = dense_leak_norm(parents = G1n1, units = 512)
G3d1, G3l1, G3n1 = dense_leak_norm(parents = G2n1, units = 1024)
G4d1 = Dense(np.prod(img_shape), activation = "tanh")(G3n1)
generator_outputs = Reshape(img_shape)(G4d1)
generator = Model(inputs = generator_inputs, outputs = generator_outputs)

# This line is required to evade the error
discriminator_inputs = generator_outputs
# If discriminator_inputs is defined using the line below, same error is reproduced
#discriminator_inputs = Input(shape = img_shape)
D1f1 = Flatten(input_shape = img_shape)(discriminator_inputs)
D1d1, D1l1 = dense_leak_norm(parents = D1f1, units = 512, bool_norm = False)
D2d1, D2l1 = dense_leak_norm(parents = D1l1, units = 256, bool_norm = False)
discriminator_outputs = Dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")(D2l1)
discriminator = Model(inputs = discriminator_inputs, outputs = discriminator_outputs)
discriminator.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = optimizer, metrics = ["accuracy"])

combined = Model(generator_inputs, discriminator_outputs)

As we can see in discriminator.summary(), the InputLayer is a clone of the generator output:
Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ keras_tensor_11CLONE (InputLayer)    │ (None, 28, 28, 1)           │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)                    │ (None, 784)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_4 (Dense)                      │ (None, 512)                 │         401,920 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 512)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_5 (Dense)                      │ (None, 256)                 │         131,328 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 256)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_6 (Dense)                      │ (None, 1)                   │             257 │

But apparently, the GAN model wouldn't train in this way.
Any idea what's going on?

I had the same problem when using Keras on my MacBook Pro M1 Pro. Downgrading the Keras version to 3.4 worked for me.

after asking around my question on Image.sc forum, I found that the problem can be solved if I downgrade keras from 3.6.0 to 3.4.1 (Google Colab version).
However, the bad news is that a new bug appeared. When I set
discriminator.compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy", optimizer = Adam(learning_rate = 0.0002, beta_1 = 0.5), metrics = ["accuracy"])
# Set non-trainable after compiling discriminator
discriminator.trainable = False

discriminator still becomes non-trainable even if it had been compiled before turning off the trainable tag, and no re-compilation of the discriminator afterwards. Please refer to discriminator.summary() before and after turning off the trainable flag.
discriminator.summary before freezing
Model: "functional_1"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer_1 (InputLayer)           │ (None, 28, 28, 1)           │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)                    │ (None, 784)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_4 (Dense)                      │ (None, 512)                 │         401,920 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 512)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_5 (Dense)                      │ (None, 256)                 │         131,328 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 256)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_6 (Dense)                      │ (None, 1)                   │             257 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 533,505 (2.04 MB)
 Trainable params: 533,505 (2.04 MB)
 Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
discriminator.summary after freezing but no recompile
Model: "functional_1"
┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓
┃ Layer (type)                         ┃ Output Shape                ┃         Param # ┃
┡━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╇━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┩
│ input_layer_1 (InputLayer)           │ (None, 28, 28, 1)           │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ flatten (Flatten)                    │ (None, 784)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_4 (Dense)                      │ (None, 512)                 │         401,920 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_3 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 512)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_5 (Dense)                      │ (None, 256)                 │         131,328 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ leaky_re_lu_4 (LeakyReLU)            │ (None, 256)                 │               0 │
├──────────────────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────────┼─────────────────┤
│ dense_6 (Dense)                      │ (None, 1)                   │             257 │
└──────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
 Total params: 533,505 (2.04 MB)
 Trainable params: 0 (0.00 B)
 Non-trainable params: 533,505 (2.04 MB)

There are a lot of reports about this tag working aberrantly
A GitHub discussion
Another GitHub discussion
To circumvent this problem, I have to turn discriminator trainable before I train it and then off before I train the entire GAN in each epoch cycle
discriminator.trainable = True
discriminator.train_on_batch(x = realhalf, y = np.ones((half_size, 1)))
discriminator.trainable = False
combined.train_on_batch(np.random.normal(0, 1, (batch_size, 100)), np.array([1] * batch_size))

But honestly I feel a bit unsecure using these packages since the bug has been there since almost a decade ago. I did a brief search and some recommended PyTorch instead (Redit discussion)? If anyone knows about these packages, please feel free to let me know. Thanks in advance!

You shouldn’t answer question with question
